# Icons disappearing from menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have the problem that occasionally on startup, icons are missing from the menu bar. This includes e.g. Clock, User name, Wi-Fi, Menu Meters and Notification Center.
It does not apply to e.g. Little Snitch, lastfm, Spotlight and Watts.
So it is not an issue of OS X versus other apps.

It looks like this:

[image]

This phenomenon appeared with Yosemite.

Comment: try log in as different user to check if it is your profile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although I do not know the problem, there are several solutions.

1. Reboot or Log out.
2. Kill the SystemUIServer process, either via Activity Monitor or via `killall SystemUIServer`. The UI server will restart and the problem will be gone. I've seen it happen that I needed to kill it twice to fully take effect.

Comment: THanks!! this worked and saved me a lot of time from rebooting every time

Comment: quitting `SystemUIServer` immediately did the trick (OS X 10.12.4).

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.  Option 2 is much better than restarting the whole thing from scratch!

Comment: It doesn't help for my one drive icon(s) (10.13)

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd add that I had this issue again in Yosemite 10.10.3. A disk repair, 10.10.3 download & reinstall, deleting SystemUI preferences `.plist`, etc. had no effect for me.

What *did* work is a simple **Safe Mode boot**. No actual changes in Safe Mode, simply booting into it fixed my system menu bar icons. A reboot back into normal mode still had them fixed.

You can access Safe Mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> right after the chime during startup.

Comment: Current instructions for booting into safe mode: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac ([WB](https://web.archive.org/web/20231026135743/https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac))

Answer (score -3):

If you write killall SystemUIServer in terminal it will fix it!

Comment: This is no different that the accepted answer from several years ago. If you have additional, updated, or different info, please add it to your answer.