# Display issue with Yosemite on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, time

Please check image

[image]

Anyone facing same issue?

Comment: maybe try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157060/icons-disappearing-from-menu-bar

Comment: @Tetsujin I checked it before positing my question. Solution on that thread didn't help though.

Comment: Is that a retina screen? & is it running at standard resolution? I don't have retina & I tried with & without the Day showing & it still fits OK for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not a retina screen and running at standard resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update fixed display issue.