# Some app icons don't show up in my menu bar anymore

Tags: menu-bar, monterey, apple-silicon

I'm running Monterey 12.4 on a recently acquired M1 2021 MBP.

For the first few weeks, it was behaving great, and two apps I frequently used properly showed in the menu bar:

- A little calendar app called `itsycal`
- `Docker desktop`

But since I restarted my MBP a few weeks ago, these apps don't show up in the menu bar anymore. `Docker desktop` is running fine, but no icon in the menu bar. `Itsycal` is now unusable since the only interface to it is via the menu bar. I tried installing `MenuMeters` which worked fine on a previous MBP, and same issue, no icon in the menu bar (which also defeats the point of having that app).

The only icons I do have are these:
[image: icons I have left]

I also have issues with the date not displaying anymore but it feels like a separate issue, which I'm mentioning just for context.

I couldn't find reports of similar incidents online. Any help to diagnose the issue and eventually fix it is welcome!

Comment: In the end, just rebooting in safe mode, like in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282926/464428), solved it.

Comment: This has happened to me too. I was using an app called Hidden Bar (to hide icons in the Menu Bar) and I thought that was the problem but I quit that app and the problem persisted. Apparently macOS Monterey has a given allocated space for icons, after that space the icons are hidden. Try moving the app far to the left (command + click, and move it) and it will show you previously hidden icons, and the app you moved gets hidden, at least that's what happens to me. If anybody has a solution, please post it!

Comment: @loco.loop no my issue is that not a single app appears, it's not about the number of apps. Booting in safe mode displays all the apps.